# Disable ubuntu keyboard shortcuts

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.04

I must have accidentally activated some keyboard shortcut function because every time I press certain keys such as <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> they act as shortcuts to things. For example if I press <kbd>f</kbd>, the search function appears. How can I stop this so I can type these letters again?

Thanks

Answer (score 123):

In System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Find the shortcut you're trying to disable, click on it to set a new shortcut, then pressing Backspace will disable that shortcut.

Comment: I remove the shortcut as described, but after system restart, removed shortcut configuration comes back.

Comment: I had to use https://askubuntu.com/a/380462/88187 to disable Ctrl+Alt+Down/Up besides what's here.

Comment: By pure chance I pressed ALT twice in a row (holding key with each press about 1 second ....) ... it seems to toggle the keys on and off alternately